# Using Inkscape extensions directly from python (not through GUI)

Tags: python, inkscape

I working on a python script which generates a big .svg file (A0 size). In order to print on my "small" printer (physically), I have a Inkscape extension (python package) which solves my problem. My question is really, if someone has experience with using these Inkscape extensions directly from a python script and how it can be done. The extension uses the index API.

I need this to work just from python, not using CLI/subprocesses

I have tried modifying the extension to be run without the GUI, but no luck.